# Ajax call in wordpress doesn't go to admin-ajax.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to call a function using ajax in a wordpress admin submenu. Here is my code.

```
jQuery('#deleteProj').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){ 
  var tobeDeleted = jQuery(this).serialize();
  alert(tobeDeleted);
  jQuery.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: ajaxurl,
     data: tobeDeleted,
     success:function(){ alert(tobeDeleted);},
     error:function(errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}
  });
  return false;
}
```

However, the code opens a new page querying the admin.php file looks like this:

```
wp/wp-admin/admin.php?q=id&action=deleteproj
```

I'm really at a loss for why this is happening. I'm calling the function from inside my plugin's admin menu

Update

The issue turned out to be that I had to define the php functions on the main file of my plugin. I also made sure to absolutely define the location of admin-ajax.php this allowed the jQuery to properly execute.

Comment: seems like you are redirecting instead of ajaxing

Comment: changing to onclick didn't help, could this be caused by me trying to call inside admin.php?

Comment: are you sure you have the js on your page, wrapped in a document ready statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#deleteProj').submit(function() {
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    var formData= jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:ajaxurl,
    action:'function_name',
    data:formData,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      // return
   }
   });
    return false; 
});
```

Regards:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are redirecting instead of ajaxing ,try changing you submit event to a click event

```
jQuery('#deleteProj').find('[type="submit"]').click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  var tobeDeleted = jQuery(this).serialize();
  alert(tobeDeleted);
  jQuery.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: ajaxurl,
     data: tobeDeleted,
     success:function(){ alert(tobeDeleted);},
     error:function(errorThrown){alert(errorThrown);}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the code in side your php file, then the answer from Gulshan is correct, but if you have written this code in a different .js file you can not access the ajax url into it. Then you need to localize  the script to add the ajax url.

Please follow the example code :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'mainscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), 'v1', true );
wp_localize_script( 'mainscript', 'sitesettings', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

for both the function you need place same handle [ 'mainscript' ], now in your main.js file you need to write the following code :

```
 jQuery('#deleteProj').submit(function() {
    var ajaxurl = sitesettings.ajaxurl; // here you are accessing the admin-ajax.php
    var formData= jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:ajaxurl,
    action:'function_name',
    data:formData,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      // return
   }   });
    return false; 
});
```

Hope this work for you